# Authorizing the user

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am having a slight problem with authorizing the admin.
The backend code works, but i have got problems with requesting the admin route and authenticating the logged in user. First thing i have tried was to put the isAdmin value in the cookies, but it wasnt secure. Then i tried to verify the admin with cookies, i used cookie.get() to get the token. But it was not a success.

code Authorization:

```
const isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
        res.status(401).send({ msg: "Not an authorized admin" });
    } else {
        res.send(req.user.isAdmin);
        // const token = req.header("auth-token");
        // const verified = verify(token, process.env.SECRET);
        // req.user = verified;
        // next();
    }
    next();
};
```

code Admin route:

`router.get("/adminPanel", isAuth, isAdmin, (req, res) => {});`

code Login page:

```
const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        Axios.post("http://localhost:5000/users/login", {
            email,
            password,
        })
            .then(response => {
                cookie.set("token", response.data.token, {
                    expires: 1,
                });

                setUser({
                    token: response.data.token,
                });
                if (response.data.isAdmin) {
                    alert("admin");
                } else {
                    alert("not an admin");
                }
                // console.log(response.data.token);
                // console.log(response.data.isAdmin);
            })

            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    };
```

code Admin page:

```
import React, { useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Axios from "axios";
import { userContext } from "../../App";

export default function Home() {
    const [user, setUser] = useContext(userContext);
    const [content, setContent] = useState("login plz to display the content");
    useEffect(() => {
        // Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users/adminPanel").then(response =>
        //  console.log(response.data),
        // );
        // async function fetchAdmin() {const result = await
        Axios.get("http://localhost:5000/users/adminPanel", {
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${user.isAdmin}`,
            },
        });
        // }
        // fetchAdmin();
        // async function fetchProtected() {
        //  const result = await (
        //      await fetch("http://localhost:5000/users/adminPanel", {
        //          method: "GET",
        //          headers: {
        //              "Content-Type": "application/json",
        //              authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}`,
        //          },
        //      })
        //  ).json();
        //  if (result.isAdmin) setContent("Admin");
        // }
        // fetchProtected();
    }, [user]);

    return `${content}`;
}
```

Getting the token from cookies:

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
    useEffect(() => {
        setUser({ token: cookie.get("token") });
    }, []);
    console.log(user);
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account your route

```
router.get("/adminPanel", isAuth, isAdmin, (req, res) => {});
```

I assume `req.user.isAdmin` is set in `isAuth` middleware, so your `isAdmin` middleware should check that parameter, let it pass if so, or reject it otherwise.

In the `isAuth` middleware after you validate the user, you should know if is an admin or not, so just set the parameter like this:

```
const isAuth = async (req, res, next) => {
  // other code
  req.user.isAdmin = true // put your logic here to reflect the status
  next(); // pass the control to next middleware, in your example to isAdmin
}
```

Finally `isAdmin` could look like this:

```
const isAdmin = async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.user.isAdmin) {
        res.status(401).send({ msg: "Not an authorized admin" });
    } else {
        next();
    }
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that doesnt resolve the problem.